# Problem understanding $\lnot$E, $\lnot$I, and RAA rule in Gentzen style proofs

Tags: logic, proof-explanation

I am self-studying Chiswell and Hodges' book and I am really confused about $\lnot$E, $\lnot$I, and RAA rule in Gentzen style proofs. (I learned Fitch style proof before, maybe that's why?) Specifically, this problem: 
[image]

I understand that $\phi$ comes as an assumption since we are proving a conditional; but where does $\lnot\phi$ come from?

Also, the application of $\lnot$I here looks like the principle of explosion to me? Why are we then able to apply the result ($\lnot\lnot\phi$) from an absurdity to the conclusion? Surely from an absurdity the only thing we can infer is that there is something wrong with our assumption.

Furthermore, here are the rules as laid out in the book; isn't $\lnot$I just the same as RAA, i.e. assume the negation of what we want to prove, then prove otherwise by deriving an absurdity? Why are they distinct from each other?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The two rules are formulated independently, because in intuitionistic logic, $\lnot$I is valid while *RAA* is not. In classical logic we can derive *RAA* from the first one using *Double Negation*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't have the book, but I would assume in this particular system being discussed double negation elimination would be *derived* from RAA. That is, I suspect the system being presented would be completely intuitionistic if RAA is removed and that RAA is *how* classical logic is introduced.

Comment: Incidentally, the principle of explosion usually corresponds to $\bot E$. In this notation, it would look like: given a derivation $\cfrac{D}{\bot}$ we can make a derivation $\cfrac{D}{\cfrac{\bot}{\psi}}$. The difference between this and $\neg I$ or RAA is that we don't get to discharge any assumptions. Personally, I find this notation for natural deduction proofs (particularly hypothetical ones) atrocious and much prefer a [sequent-based approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_deduction#Tree-like_presentations) which doesn't require non-local changes to the derivation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you understand why $\varphi$ was added as an assumption, then you can understand why $\neg\varphi$ is added. You can easily show that the $\neg E$ and $\neg I$ are instances of $\to\!\!E$ and $\to\!\!I$ if we were to take $\neg\varphi$ as just a shorthand for $\varphi\to\bot$.

Comment: The only way I can make sense of it being assumed, is that the combination of $\lnot$E and $\lnot$I is a proof by contradiction. Because if we want to derive $\lnot\lnot\phi$, and at the end of $\lnot$I we get it, this looks just like a proof by contradiction to me.

 But I doubt this is the case here because the book explicitly introduced RAA as an distinct rule from $\lnot$E and $\lnot$I, which is why I am so confused!

Comment: So you understand why you would assume $\phi$ when proving $\phi\to\dots$ but not why you would assume $\neg\phi$ when proving $\neg\phi\to\dots$? "Proof by contradiction" is an ambiguous phrase that is often used for both $\neg I$ and RAA. The problem is that people get used to treating $\neg\neg\phi$ as identical to $\phi$. That is a statement that needs to be proven and need not be true. How are you going to prove it from just $\neg I$? In particular, how are you going to prove the $\neg\neg\phi\to\phi$ direction since the conclusion of $\neg I$ always contains a negation?

Comment: Another issue that seems to be present is that these rules are a *definition* of a formal logic. You seem to want to import your previous knowledge and use it to prove the statements. This both misses and defeats the point. The only question is if the rules are correctly applied. We can assume $\phi$ because $\to I$ allows it. We can assume $\neg\phi$ because $\neg I$ allows it. Whether or not these rules correspond to traditional "laws of logic" is irrelevant which is the point. We don't need to know logic to use this system, we just need to be able to verify correct application of the rules.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation (I am really stuck here so I really appreciate it). I understand the legitimacy of assuming $\phi$ because it fits with daily life reasoning - e.g. so we want to show that if $\phi$ then $\lnot\lnot\phi$, ok let's for the sake of argument assume that the antecedent $\phi$ is true...etc. IF we are to prove $\lnot\phi\to...$ then sure assuming $\lnot\phi$ seems reasonable. But in the example $\phi\to\lnot\lnot\phi$ I just don't see how $\lnot\phi$ can act as the antecedent so as to be assumed. (Not to mention $\phi$ as the antecedent has already been assumed)

Comment: As I said in my answer, $\neg\phi$ is logically equivalent to $\phi\to\bot$. You can use $\neg E$, $\neg I$, $\to E$, and $\to I$ to prove this. Therefore, $\phi\to\neg\neg\phi$ is logically equivalent to $\phi\to(\neg\phi\to\bot)$. As I said in my second comment, when studying formal logic, the goal is to produce a formal proof in the given formal system. You can (sometimes) use your understanding of informal logic to guide the search for a formal proof, but at the end of the day a formal proof is a derivation. You have to present the derivation, not an informal argument.

Answer (score 1):

You are proving $\vdash \phi\to\lnot\lnot\phi$ by way of Gentzen's presentation, which has a Fitch-style equivalent.$$\def\fitch#1#2{\hspace{1.75ex}\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\\hline #2\end{array}}\require{enclose}\require{cancel}
\enclose{circle}{\small 1}\dfrac{\enclose{circle}{\small 2}\dfrac{\dfrac{\cancelto 1{~~\phi~~}\cancelto 2{~~\lnot\phi~~}}{\bot}{\small\lnot\textsf E}}{\lnot\lnot\phi}{\small\lnot\textsf I}}{\phi\to\lnot\lnot\phi}{\small\to\!\textsf I}\qquad\fitch{}{\fitch{~1.~\phi}{\fitch{~2.~\lnot\phi}{~3.~\bot\hspace{4.25ex}\lnot\textsf E,1,2}\\~4.~\lnot\lnot\phi\hspace{4.5ex}\lnot\textsf I, 2{-}3}\\~5.~\phi\to\lnot\lnot\phi\hspace{2.5ex}{\to}\textsf I,1{-} 4}$$

> I understand that $ϕ$ comes as an assumption since we are proving a conditional; but where does $¬ϕ$ come from?

They are both assumptions. As indicated by the indices on the strikethroughs, assumption of $\phi$ is discharged by the rule of *conditional introduction*, while the assumption of $\lnot\phi$ is discharged by the rule of *negation introduction*.   The Fitch presentation also shows where the assumptions are raised and discharged.

> Also, the application of $¬$ I here looks like the principle of explosion to me? Why are we then able to apply the result ($¬¬ϕ$) from an absurdity to the conclusion?

The distinction is that *ex falso quodlibet* derives a new proposition *within the same context* as the absurdity, while *negation introduction* is a rule that *discharges* the assumption from which the absurdity was derived.

The usage of this rule is similar to *conditional introduction*; indeed, if negation is defined as the implication of absurdity ($\lnot\phi\equiv\phi\to\bot$), then the above proofs would only use the *conditional* rules.

$$\enclose{circle}{\small 1}\dfrac{\enclose{circle}{\small 2}\dfrac{\dfrac{\cancelto 1{~~\phi~~}\cancelto 2{~~\phi\to\bot~~}}{\bot}{\small\to\textsf E}}{(\phi\to\bot)\to\bot}{\small\to\textsf I}}{\phi\to((\phi\to\bot)\to\bot)}{\small\to\!\textsf I}\qquad\fitch{}{\fitch{~1.~\phi}{\fitch{~2.~\phi\to\bot}{~3.~\bot\hspace{15ex}{\to}\textsf E,1,2}\\~4.~(\phi\to\bot)\to\bot\hspace{6ex}{\to}\textsf I, 2{-}3}\\~5.~\phi\to((\phi\to\bot)\to\bot)\hspace{2ex}{\to}\textsf I,1{-} 4}$$

> Surely from an absurdity the only thing we can infer is that there is something wrong with our assumption.

Precisely so.   Since an absurdity is derived from the assumption then we may discharge that assumption and deduce that its negation is true.   In this proof, the assumption being discharged is $\lnot\phi$.

That is that from $\Gamma,\lnot\phi\vdash\bot$ we infer $\Gamma\vdash\lnot\lnot\phi$.

> Furthermore, here are the rules as laid out in the book; isn't $¬$I just the same as RAA, i.e. assume the negation of what we want to prove, then prove otherwise by deriving an absurdity? Why are they distinct from each other?

**RAA** is a combination of *negation introduction* and *double negation elimination*. $$\dfrac{\enclose{circle}{\small 1}\dfrac{\cancelto 1{~~ \lnot\phi~~}\\\quad\vdots\\\quad\bot}{\lnot\lnot\phi}{\lnot\textsf I}}{\phi}{\lnot\lnot\textsf E}$$

*Negation Elimination* is the rule for a Proof *of* Negation: where one assumes a claim aiming to derive a contradiction and so deduce that *its negation holds*.   From $\psi\vdash\bot$ infer that $\vdash\lnot\psi$.

*Reduction to Absurdity* is the rule for a Proof *by* Contradiction, where one *assumes the negation* of a claim aiming to derive a contradiction and so deduce that *the claim* holds.  From $\lnot\psi\vdash\bot$ infer that $\vdash\psi$.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that $\phi$ comes as an assumption since we are proving a conditional; but where does $\lnot\phi$ come from?

The $\lnot\phi$ is also an assumption, and since that assumption together with the $\phi$ leads to a contradiction, you use $\neg$ I to derive $\neg (\neg \phi)$.

> Also, the application of $\lnot$I here looks like the principle of explosion to me?

No ... it's the formalization of the proof by contradiction.

> Why are we then able to apply the result ($\lnot\lnot\phi$) from an absurdity to the conclusion?

Again, they don't use the principle of explosion here. That is, they don;t derive $\neg (\neg \phi)$ form the contradiction, but rather derive $\neg (\neg \phi)$ from the fact that the assumption $\neg \phi$ leads to a contradiction.

> Surely from an absurdity the only thing we can infer is that there is something wrong with our assumption.

Not true. From a contradiction we can infer anything! Typically, this would be formalized using a $\bot$ E rule:  from $\bot$ derive any statement $\phi$

> isn't $\neg$ I just the same as RAA

No, it is not. $\neg I$ infers $\neg \phi$ if $\phi$ leads to a contradiction, whereas RAA infers $\phi$ if $\neg \phi$ leads to a contradiction. In non-classical logics, that makes a big difference.

Finally, their $\neg $ E is pretty weird in that it doesn't seem to eliminate any $\neg$'s at all ... I would call that rule $\bot$ I

Comment: @DerekElkins You're right, my bad. I'll update my answer, thanks!

Comment: So he is attempting to prove by contradiction, thus $\lnot\phi$ is assumed? That makes sense I suppose...but then if $\lnot$E and $\lnot$I work together as a proof by contradiction, why do we still need RAA? Or, what's the difference between RAA and the combination of $\lnot$E and $\lnot$I?

Comment: When I learned Fitch style proof (on software developed by UCLA) we didn't have $\lnot$E or $\lnot$I - we have only a proof by contradiction approach and afterwards we would use something similar to ⊥ to signify a contradiction has been reached and thus otherwise is true. So this is all very confusing to me...

Comment: @DanielMak Interesting ... I wonder how that system did without any $\neg$ rules ... Do you have a working link to that system?

Comment: I suppose proof by contradiction is, in a sense, $\lnot$I; but I don't think we have anything similar to $\lnot$E. That's why I am so confused - because what that example has been doing with $\lnot$E and $\lnot$I seem to me is essentially the same as RAA/proof by contradiction

[link](https://logiclx.humnet.ucla.edu/Logic/Documents/CORE/LogicText%20Chap%201%20Aug%202013.pdf)

[link](https://logiclx.humnet.ucla.edu/Logic/Documents/CORE/LogicText%20Chap%202%20Aug%202013.pdf)

Comment: @Bram28 As I state in my answer, $\neg I$ and $\neg E$ directly correspond to $\to I$ and $\to E$, so the naming seems reasonable enough to me. I find your statement strange, as $\neg E$ "eliminates" just as many $\neg$s as $\to E$ eliminates $\to$s. On the other hand, I would *never* write $\bot I$. Structural proof theory and categorical logic both make it pretty clear that there should be no introduction rule for $\bot$.